# Error while reindexing product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, reindex

On re-indexing product attribute I have found below error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xxxxxxx`.`catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_eav` (`entity_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `value`) SELECT `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`attribute_id`, `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`store_id`, `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`value` FROM `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`)There was a problem with reindexing process.

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: disable the flat catalog, remove the tables catalog_product_flat_store_* if have, then try to process reIndexing and then enable flat tables again.

Comment: You can use putty instead of using default re-indexing

Comment: I am using console already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this step

1. Disable the flat catalog, remove the tables catalog_product_flat_store_
2. Reindex
3. And enable flat tables again.